# How to prevent event from loading twice on Button press in MAUI?

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui

how can I prevent the event from loading twice when the button is pressed twice quickly in my MAUI Project?

I expect a single page to open when the button is pressed twice quickly.

When you gently touch the button, one page opens. When you quickly double click, 2 pages open.

Comment: use a bool flag in your code to track if the page has already been loaded

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be helpful if you could provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and tell us what have you already tried to do to fix it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a bool flag

Here is a little example from my custom datepicker

```
private bool isDatePickerOpen = false;

private async void OnShowPickerButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (isDatePickerOpen) return; // If the datepicker is already open  
            isDatePickerOpen = true;
           // other code
            isDatePickerOpen = false; // reset the flag.
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=net-7.0) for this. Much becuase it is thread safe. SemaphoreSlim allows a thread to execute its task one at a time, if that is what you want.

you define it like this

```cs
private SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new(1, 1);
```

Then in your `Button_CLick` event you use it like this:

```cs
if(semaphoreSlim.CurrentCount == 0)
{
   return;
}

await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();

try
{
   // Logic for button
}
finally
{
   semaphoreSlim.Release();
}
```

First you guard if the CurrentCount is 0 (see the documentation), meaning that the Event is already on its way. Then you call the semaphore in a wait. When you are done with your task you release it and the button is ready for next press.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `Timer` to achieve this.

We could add a variable(e.g.`clickCount`)  to record the number of times we click during a `TimeSpan`(e.g. `1s`).

Please refer to the following code:

```
//define variable clickCount to record the times of clicking Button
private static int clickCount;

private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        if (clickCount < 1)
        {
            TimeSpan tt = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

            Device.StartTimer(tt, ClickHandle);

        }
        clickCount++;
    }



    bool ClickHandle()
    {
        if (clickCount > 1)
        {
            // Minus1(_sender);
            DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have clicked more than one times during the timespan", "OK");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("----add your code here");
        }
        else
        {
            // Plus1(_sender);
            DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have clicked the button one time during the timespan", "OK");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("----add your code here");
        }

        clickCount = 0;

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Furkan Hıdır, may I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.